# jquery mobile onclick function not working as expected

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

In the following when i click on `one` div i see the alert 10 times.What am i doing wrong.I am using phone gap framework with jquery for mobile..`deals_list.length=10`

```
function test_this(f)
{
    alert("this");
}

function load_div()
{
   var html = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < deals_list.length; i++) {
     html += '<div class="list" onclick="test_this('+deals_list[i]["id"]+');" id="'+deals_list[i]["id"]+'">..</div>';

   $("#flow").append(html)

   }
}
```

Comment: You are allegedly using jQuery then why are you using `onclick` in first place?

Comment: can u give an example and also tell me what am i doing wrong. this is jquery mobile..

Comment: well not really jquery mobile ;-) Is this your code or just an extract? I ask because there are some strange things in it: Where is the html variable? (like this you would add more and more lines to #flow, because html grows in each loop) Why don't you use .live for the click event?

Comment: it is just an extract i have initialed the html variable .Please see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete my comment above, I think it is because your load div function has some problems, this is how I would do it:

```
 // bind your function to div.list
 $( '.list' ).live( 'click', test_this );

 // your test function gets event object and ui
 function test_this( event, ui ) {
   // do whatever you want onclick
 }

 function load_div() {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < deals_list.length; i++) {
       html += '<div class="list" id="'+deals_list[i]["id"]+'">..</div>';
    }
    $("#flow").append(html);
 }
```

Comment: @Rajeev Well doesn't change anything, fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/xMSkH/1/ How do you initialize the load_div?

Comment: It is called from a another function which inturn is called in device ready function

Comment: your answer works but the problem was with css.A div was overlapping eachother .Fixed css problem got resolved.Thanks for the help